# Error caused by "Mirror Vertex Group"

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have prepared a simple .blend that demonstrates the issue in question.

[image]

I select the vertices of which I want the weights to be mirrored over to the other side (along X).

[image: Weight of 1 has been added to vertices of one bone group]

I click the "Mirror" button.

[image: Weight Tools - Mirror]

An error appears: "4 vertices mirrored, 10 failed"

[image: Vertex mirroring failed]

Even stranger than the fact that Blender is reporting 10 failed when only 4 were selected, is that in actuality *all* of them appear to have failed!

I have the "Show Zero Weights" option set to "All", and the mesh turns completely gray after mirroring, meaning all weights are being lost in the process of trying to mirror.

[image: Showing zero weights for all vertex groups]

[image: After trying to Mirror, all vertex weights are now gone!]

I'm hoping someone can explain what causes such errors, and what I should be doing differently. Thanks.

Related external links:

- [Blender Manual - Weight Tools](https://www.blender.org/manual/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/tools.html)
- [A similar but inconclusive post on CG Cookie](http://community.cgcookie.com/t/mirroring-weight-paint/1736)

Comment: It works for me if I select both source and target verts / faces. It's not quite clear from [tool's page in manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/tools.html#mirror) about whether it should be like that.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks! If I select the verts on each side it works. Cool! So that is solved. Now if I can just understand why it's throwing an error message and where it's getting the "10 verts" figure from...